# Prevent constructor method misspelling

Tags: typescript, ecmascript-6

One of the most common ES6-specific mistakes I've encountered is misspelled `constructor` method.

Obviously, this won't have any effect, because a class has default constructor method:

```
interface IConstructor {
    constructor: Function;
}

class Foo implements IConstructor {
  contructor() { ... }
}
```

How can this problem be addressed with TypeScript, preferably at compilation time?

Comment: *"One of the most common ES6-specific mistakes I've encountered is misspelled constructor method."* -- I feel the same with ReactJS. Just writing `componentDldMount` (see the misspell?) will fail silently, leaving you to track down the hideous bug yourself (not mentioning that you need to type the method name yourself all the time). This is why I generally dismiss APIs that provide hooks by exact method name matching. What you could do here is create a snippet in your IDE that creates the constructor method on, say, writing `ctor`.

Comment: @JohnWeisz Yes, snippets may work. But it is still may be painful if you do a prototype in Plunker. In Angular 2, hook methods are forced through interfaces, `class Foo implements OnInit`. I guess, a similar thing can be done with Flow.

Comment: The problem with Angular 2 as well is that there is no way to force an optional hook method to be spelled right (besides distributing methods through multiple interfaces, but I'd say that's just as much prone to errors). You could say that `constructor` is an optional native hook method. A decorator-based approach is, IMO, much better, although decorators cannot be used with constructors, unfortunately. You cannot misspell, say, `@componentDidMount`, because it is detected by the TypeScript compiler.

Comment: @JohnWeisz It is still can be done with interfaces. All of Angular hooks are optional, `implements OnInit` is there exactly to make sure that this hook won't be misspelled or forgotten in class implementation.

Comment: This is one (and not the only one) thing they did right in c++: constructors are syntactically different there because they don't have return type. And constructor must have name that matches class name exactly. So if you misspell it, compiler will complain about invalid function declaration. For typescript, I can think of tslint rule that will require return types declared for everything except constructors. However, many people like it when compiler deduces types for them, so this rule will be less than useful..

Comment: @estus You might be interested in upvoting this feature request: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/8476

Comment: @AsadSaeeduddin Thanks, looks like 2.4 is the milestone. Do you have ideas how this will help with the subject? I've got none.

Comment: @estus If someone forgets to initialize some properties via the constructor (or misspells the constructor), you'll get a compiler error.

Comment: @AsadSaeeduddin Won't work in every case, but yes, this makes sense, I'm looking forward to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't safeguard against it, not easily.

You can work around it, for example:

```
class Base {
    protected constructor() {}
}

class A extends Base {
    contructor() { }
}

let a = new A(); // error: Constructor of class 'Base' is protected and only accessible within the class declaration
```

([code in playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=class%20Base%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20protected%20constructor()%20%7B%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20A%20extends%20Base%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20contructor()%20%7B%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Alet%20a%20%3D%20new%20A()%3B%20%2F%2F%20error%3A%20Constructor%20of%20class%20'Base'%20is%20protected%20and%20only%20accessible%20within%20the%20class%20declaration))

But that's far from being ideal.

Comment: Thanks. Not ideal (needs extra `super()`) but already very good.

Comment: Not only does it require calling `super()`, it requires to subclass a base class. If you're already doing that then it's not an issue, otherwise it feels redundant. But I can't think of another way of getting a compilation error for it.

Answer (score 2):

The best way to safeguard against this and save on typing is to use a snippet in your text editor to create a constructor.

For example, in my editor I just type in `ctor` then hit tab and it creates a default constructor for me. You'll have to look up how to do this in whatever editor your using. Most editors support snippets (if not, you should switch editors).

Writing extra code just to prevent this problem is overkill for sure.

Answer (score 1):

An interface is an agreement between the type and consumers of the type. If you are trying to ensure that the class can be instantiated without any arguments by consuming code, you're already done. Whether or you declare a zero-parameter constructor, consumers of the type can instantiate it without any arguments.

If on the other hand you're trying to use the type system to ensure that a zero-parameter constructor is defined that does *something*, that is not really a task static type checking is well suited for. Maybe look at verifying this in your unit tests.

In other words, this:

```
class Foo implements IConstructor {
}
```

Is not meaningfully different from this:

```
class Foo implements IConstructor {
  constructor() {}
}
```

The only difference that matters:

```
class Foo implements IConstructor {
  constructor() {
      // ...
      /* Is this */
      // ...
  }
}
```

And verifying the behavior of that part is better suited to unit tests than the type checker.

Comment: Yes, this is the problem that can be addressed with unit tests. But most of the benefits of Typescript can be substituted by test coverage as well. One of the reasons why Typescript is great is that it can detect the problems at design time.

Comment: @estus Saying that most of the benefits of TypeScript can be substituted with unit tests does not make a good case for the reverse. Most tools available to you in unit tests cannot and should not be crammed into the type checker.

Comment: That's true. Just think that this case belongs to type checker. It's sad that implied constructor don't allow to handle this in TS in a reasonable way. Another problem is that constructor method (`Foo.prototype.constructor`) cannot be spied in unit tests, so the tests should be indirect, and the dev wastes some time on figuring out why the test fails. Moreover, most times I've personally had problems with misspelled constructor were quick prototypes that had no test coverage and just resulted in wasted time.

Comment: @estus You still have a no-parameter constructor to your class if you have a typo like `consrtuctor`. What you're trying to verify is that an object instantiated with no parameters *does the right thing*, as opposed to doing nothing. Usually this "thing" will be initializing some state on the instance. If you're writing tests, you can easily assert for this. If you're just knocking out a prototype, you can verify this using the usual code exploration with a debugger/REPL.

Comment: It's too easy to see the problem post facto. But in IRL scenarios the investigation why the property isn't there is a show-stopper, and the answer isn't always obvious. At the moments when I usually write tests, the problems with constructor are already debugged and resolved, and the time is lost. And test-first approach isn't always practical or possible. That's why I'm positive that it would be better to prevent this kind of typos with TS if possible. Just because it's usually too late to detect them with tests.

Answer (score 0):

That's basically a method declaration. You can not prevent misspelled derived methods.

Comment: You can. Via interface. But not with `constructor` (not my downvote, btw).

Comment: The Interface forces you to implement the interface method. It does not hinder you to implement anything else in this case a misspelled method name.

Comment: The problem is not there is misspelled `contructor` method, it doesn't hurt by itself. The problem is that there's no explicitly defined non-default `constructor` method, while `Foo` class supposed to have it. For other methods it could be prevented by extending an abstract class with abstract method, but it won't work for constructor method.

Answer (score 0):

To solve the problem with constructor method misspelling, I've ended up with the interface that covers all misprints I usually have that are hard to notice.

```
interface IConstructor {
    constructor: Function;
    constuctor?: void;
    construtor?: void;
    contructor?: void;
    cnstructor?: void;
    // ...
}

// Type '() => void' is not assignable to type 'void'.
class Foo implements IConstructor {
  contructor() {  }
}
```

It doesn't address the problem when constructor method is supposed to be specified but is missing.

More drastic approach is to use a subclass, as [the other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41616417/3731501) suggests.